# Como listar sólo el apellido del supersivor de los empleados en la tabla employees en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Volviendo a replantear mi pregunta y a si solicitarles de nuevo por favor su apoyo.

Como puedo mostrar el apellido del empleado y el código de empleado junto al apellido y código de supervisor del supervisor del empleado.

En la tabla employees:

Veo que toda la informacion estaria en la misma tabla de Employees, estaría en la columna EmployeeID que tiene los códigos de los empleados y seguido el LastName y en el campo ReportsTo es el que indica quien es el supervisor del empleado. Por ejemplo: El empleado 1 con cargo de (Sales representatives) su supervisor seria (segun columna ReportsTo) el empleado 2 que tiene cargo de Vice Presidente Sales

Sintaxis.

```
select LastName, EmployeeID, ReportsTo
from employees
```

Y que se pueda visualizar de esta forma:

LastName     EmployeeID   LastName  ReportsTo
Devolio        1          Fuller        2
Leverling      3          Fuller        2
Peacock        4          Fuller        2
Buchanan       5          Fuller        2
Suyama         6          Buchanan      5
king           7          Buchanan      5

Comment: y ccomo seria la tabla RerpotsTo? esto se soluciona con un join o con una subquery

Comment: Saludos, el campo RerpotsTo contiene el numero que indica quien es el supervisor del empleado  me podrias ayuda en como armas el join o la subquery por favor.

Comment: Intentaste algo? ya que estas tratando de aprender, ya leiste como funciona un join o como funciona una subquery?

Comment: Si revise varios materiales sin embargo trate por esta vía pero no me listo valores                                                                                                   
 SELECT     
LastName,
EmployeeID,      
c.EmployeeID,    
c.ReportsTo,    
count(o.LastName)as employees
 FROM     
 c.LastName,        
LEFT OUTER JOIN    
employees o ON c.LastName,  = o.EmployeeID,  
GROUP BY LastName, EmployeeID, ReportsTo,

Comment: que fue lo que no funciono de la respuesta que aceptaste porque funcionaba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como el nombre del supervisor está en otra tabla, llamémosla supervisor, tenés que unir ambas tablas. Se hace de dos formas, pero de las dos maneras se unen las tablas mediante una clave primaria y una foranea:

1.

```
select e.LastName, e.EmployeeID, e.ReportsTo, s.LastName
from employees e, supervisor s 
where e.ReportsTo = s.SupervisorId
```

SupervisorId es la clave primaria de la tabla donde tenes los datos del supervisor, así que solo tenes que buscar dicha tabla y ver como se llama la clave primaria para 
luego reemplazar SupervisorId por ese nombre

2. ```
   select e.LastName, e.EmployeeID, e.ReportsTo, s.LastName
   from employees e join supervisor s on e.ReportsTo = s.SupervisorId
   ```

y en realidad también existe una tercer forma que es usando subconsulta

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero la primeraforma es algo antigua y solo se usaba en Oracle cuando la misma no soportaba Joins.

Comment: Seguramente. Pero la mostré solo con fin didáctico, para que entienda como se relacionan las tablas mediante claves

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo con el código de la consulta que muestras en la zona de comentarios, estas tratando de relacionar 2 tablas: `employees` y `supervisor`

Entonces algunas observaciones:

- Deberías usar `JOIN` o `INNER JOIN` para poder obtener los registros de ambas tablas que estén relacionados
- Deberías igualar en el `ON` la llave primaria con la llave foránea
- No veo por que usar `COUNT` pues en tu enunciado solo buscas el `id` y `nombre` del empleado así como el `id` y `nombre` del supervisor al que le reporta entonces tampoco deberías usar `GROUP BY`

Considero que tu consulta debería ser de este modo:

```
SELECT  employees.id,
        employees.name,
        supervisor.id,
        supervisor.lastName
FROM supervisor
JOIN employees ON supervisor.id = employees.EmployeeID;
```

El código:

- Selecciona de cada tabla las columnas deseadas
- En el `FROM` apuntamos a la tabla `supervisor`
- En el `JOIN` apuntamos a la tabla `employees`
- En el `ON` igualamos a las llaves primarias y foráneas para que de este modo solo tomemos los valores que tienen un valor asociado en la otra tabla

> Solo deberías verificar los nombres de las tablas y las columnas para adaptar el ejemplo que te he dejado, ya que pudieran variar.

El `JOIN` o `INNER JOIN` van a traer todos los registros que de la tabla izquierda tengan un registro asociado con la tabla de la derecha, desechando todos los demás