# ¿Cómolistar el apellido y código del empleado junto al apellido y código del supervisor en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Volviendo a replantear mi pregunta y a si solicitarles de nuevo por favor su apoyo.

Como puedo mostrar el apellido del empleado y el código de empleado junto al apellido y código de supervisor del supervisor del empleado.

En la tabla employees:

Veo que toda la informacion estaria en la misma tabla de Employees, estaría en la columna EmployeeID que tiene los códigos de los empleados y seguido el LastName y en el campo ReportsTo es el que indica quien es el supervisor del empleado. Por ejemplo: El empleado 1 con cargo de (Sales representatives) su supervisor seria (segun columna ReportsTo) el empleado 2 que tiene cargo de Vice Presidente Sales

Sintaxis.

```
select LastName, EmployeeID, ReportsTo
from employees
```

Y que se pueda visualizar de esta forma:

LastName     EmployeeID   LastName  ReportsTo
Devolio        1          Fuller        2
Leverling      3          Fuller        2
Peacock        4          Fuller        2
Buchanan       5          Fuller        2
Suyama         6          Buchanan      5
king           7          Buchanan      5

Comment: Me da la impresión que lo que tienes mal es esto: `e.ReportsTo=ReportsTo` no debiera ser algo así: `e.ReportsTo=s.EmployeeID `?

Comment: Por qué haces un `join employees` sí la tabla a la que estás consultando es la misma?

Comment: Me parece un duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298853/como-listar-s%c3%b3lo-el-apellido-del-supersivor-de-los-empleados-en-la-tabla-employe

Comment: Absolutamente, de hecho deberías revisar la respuesta de @Aprendiz que es la que realmente responde mejor a tu pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, pues les pido nuevamente de su ayuda dado que con la primera respuesta no me funciono.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta anterior indicando lo tratado y el problema que presentas y sugiero que si no está respondida, entonces no marqués respuestas como aceptadas, pues eso indica que ya fue resuelta

Comment: En la pregunta original mencionas que empleados y supervisores están en dos tablas separadas, y en esta lo que dices que ambos están en la misma tabla. De cualquier forma el mecanismo del join ya esta explicado en la pregunta original ¿Que dificultades has tenido?

Comment: Me equivoque Patricio, veo que toda la informacion estaria en la misma tabla de Employees, estaría en la columna EmployeeID que tiene los códigos de los empleados y seguido el LastName y en el campo ReportsTo es el que indica quien es el supervisor del empleado.                                                    
                                                                                                                       Por ejemplo: El empleado 1 con cargo de (Sales representatives) su supervisor seria (segun columna ReportsTo) el empleado 2 que tiene cargo de Vice Presidente Sales.

Answer (score 0):

no se si entendi bien lo que ocupas, pero si deseas concatenar campos entonces busca la funcion CONCAT() , ejemplo:

```
    CONCAT(EmployeeID,' ', cargo) AS datoEmpleado
```

eso te devolvera:

```
     datoEmpleado = 1 Sales representatives
```

Comment: Gracias Oscar, estoy aprendiendo del tema, por favor orientame como puedo armar ese query, seria de esta forma:  select LastName, EmployeeID, ReportsTo
from employees
CONCAT(EmployeeID,' ', ReportsTo) AS datoEmpleado

Comment: te servira mirar la documentacion , revisa la siguiente pagina: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Comment: despues de la sentencia select va lo que deseas mostrar, en este caso si le dices que mostraras el lastName, EmployeeID y despues pones el concat entonces estaras mostrando dos veces la misma informacion , el concat funciona para combinar mas de un dato y te lo devuleve como 1, ya no necesitas especificar antes los datos antes mencionados a menos que los necesites tambien por separado

Comment: La documentación oficial es esta Óscar https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat lo otro solo es un sitio con ejemplos

Comment: Cierto, por la rapidez puse lo primero que apareció que pudiera servir.